# What is the best way to configure lamp server's timezone (for API purposes)?

Tags: mysql, apache, api, timezone, lamp

We have a LAMP + Lumen API setup in Ubuntu 14.04 in EC2 US-West Oregon. It is used as an API server.

Server: `UTC`

MySQL configuration is:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| +00:00             | +00:00              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Other test

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP);
+--------------------------------+
| TIMEDIFF(NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP) |
+--------------------------------+
| 00:00:00                       |
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

On my.cnf

```
default_time_zone='+00:00'
```

Lumen .env configuration

```
No information about changing timezones
```

We want to know if we're doing well and if there are other considerations to modify or use a different configuration.

We see this server is not physically in UTC so that's why this came to us.

Comment: Actually the purpose of this question is to know if there was some tips about configuration about timezones. And as @dsz requested the question **How to serve correct timestaps and datetimes to clients in different timezones.**

Comment: You're still being very broad. Why would UTC not be "correct" particularly fire an API server. I request you accept my answer and come back with a new question with a specific scenario with which you can seek help.

Answer (score 1):

Web servers (in fact, most servers) are best configured as UTC, since their clients could be connecting from anywhere in the world.  Choosing a time-zone for the display of web pages is frequently done on a per-user or per-session (using GeoIP lookup) basis.  Please edit you're question if there is a **specific** question you're concerned with.

Comment: Thank you for your orientation, actually you cleared a question between lines. I'll edit.